# how to map a new post in react with axios?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

Hi everyone I am making a website for creating an events and I am connecting my backend node code to the frontend react code. The error says **TypeError: this.state.events.map is not a function
Events.render**

```
  189 | />
  190 | 
  191 | {/* body of the page */}
> 192 | <div className="card-deck" style={{ marginTop: 60 }}>
      | ^  193 |   {this.state.events.map(event => (
  194 |     <div className="col-4">
  195 |       <div
```

**this is where the error is occurring.**

```
          {this.state.events.map(event => (
            <div className="col-4">
              <div
                class="card mb-5 shadow"
                style={{
                  borderRadius: 20,
                  maxWidth: 300,
                  minWidth: 250,
                  minHeight: 450,
                  maxHeight: 450
                }}
              ><div className="card-deck" style={{ marginTop: 60 }}>
          {this.state.events.map(event => (
            <div className="col-4">
              <div
                class="card mb-5 shadow"
                style={{
                  borderRadius: 20,
                  maxWidth: 300,
                  minWidth: 250,
                  minHeight: 450,
                  maxHeight: 450
                }}
              >
```

**this is the componentDidMount function**

```
        const { data } = await getCategories();
        const categories = [{ _id: "", name: "All Categories" }, ...data];

        const { data: events } = await getEvents();
        this.setState({ events, categories });

        console.log(events);
      }
```

**this the eventService file where its getting the events from the backend**

```
const apiEndPoint = 'http://localhost:3100/api/events';

export function getEvents(){
    return http.get(apiEndPoint);
}

export function deleteEvent(eventId){
    return http.delete(apiEndPoint + '/' + eventId)
}
```

**this is the state**

````
    events: getEvents(),
    user: getUser(),
    users: getUsers(),
    showDetails: false,
    shownEventID: 0,
    showUserProfile: false,
    shownUserID: 0,
    searchQuery: ""
  };```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `componentDidMount` is invoked, React invokes the `render()` method, and when that happens your `this.state.events` is not an Array, making `.map` not a function.

To solve this:

In your constructor, set `events` to an empty Array

```
{
   events: []
   //Rest of the state...
}
```

Then when the component first renders (before `componentDidMount` is invoked), `this.state.events` will be an empty array, which means that `.map()` will be a function and it won't throw that error. After that `componentDidMount` is invoked, making the API call and populating your state, this causes a re-render and your UI should be populated.

Extra Note: you shouldn't make API calls in your constructor, that's what `componentDidMount` is for.

Answer (score 0):

When your component is first rendered, check if the state.events is an array since `map` can only be used with array.